# Content not loading from class

Tags: c#, xna-4.0, game-physics

Im trying to build a break out game using C# and the XNA framework. I've placed the brick into a seperate class and created an array for 10 bricks to load. However, when I run the game, no bricks are actually appearing and I can't seem to find the error as Visual Studio isn't flagging anything.

**Brick class:**

```
class bricks
{
    Texture2D brickimg;
    Rectangle rectangle;
    int[] brickXPos = new int[50];
    int[] brickYPos = new int[50];

    public bricks(Texture2D NewTexture, Rectangle newRectangle)
    {
        brickimg  = NewTexture;
        rectangle = newRectangle;
    }

    public void Initialize()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
        {
            brickXPos[i] = 300 + i * 60;
            brickYPos[i] = 100;
        }
    }

    public void Update()
    {
    }

    public void Draw(SpriteBatch spritebatch)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
        {
           spritebatch.Draw(brickimg, new Vector2(brickXPos[i], brickYPos[i]), rectangle, Color.White);
        }
    }
}
```

**Main program:**

```
/// <summary>
/// This is the main type for your game
/// </summary>
public class Breakout : Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game
{
    GraphicsDeviceManager graphics;
    SpriteBatch spriteBatch;
    Texture2D BackgroundImg;
    bricks bricks;

    public Breakout()
    {
        graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this);

        graphics.PreferredBackBufferWidth = 1024;
        graphics.PreferredBackBufferHeight = 768;
        graphics.ApplyChanges();
        Content.RootDirectory = "Content";
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Allows the game to perform any initialization it needs to before starting to run.
    /// This is where it can query for any required services and load any non-graphic
    /// related content.  Calling base.Initialize will enumerate through any components
    /// and initialize them as well.
    /// </summary>
    protected override void Initialize()
    {
        // TODO: Add your initialization logic here

        base.Initialize();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// LoadContent will be called once per game and is the place to load
    /// all of your content.
    /// </summary>
    protected override void LoadContent()
    {
        // Create a new SpriteBatch, which can be used to draw textures.
        spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice);
        BackgroundImg = Content.Load<Texture2D>("starfield");
        bricks = new bricks(Content.Load<Texture2D>("redbrick"),new Rectangle());
        // TODO: use this.Content to load your game content here
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// UnloadContent will be called once per game and is the place to unload
    /// all content.
    /// </summary>
    protected override void UnloadContent()
    {
        // TODO: Unload any non ContentManager content here
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Allows the game to run logic such as updating the world,
    /// checking for collisions, gathering input, and playing audio.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="gameTime">Provides a snapshot of timing values.</param>
    protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        // Allows the game to exit
        if (GamePad.GetState(PlayerIndex.One).Buttons.Back == ButtonState.Pressed)
            this.Exit();

        // TODO: Add your update logic here

        base.Update(gameTime);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// This is called when the game should draw itself.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="gameTime">Provides a snapshot of timing values.</param>
    protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.CornflowerBlue);

        // TODO: Add your drawing code here

        base.Draw(gameTime);
        spriteBatch.Begin();
            spriteBatch.Draw(BackgroundImg, Vector2.Zero, Color.White);
            bricks.Draw(spriteBatch);
            spriteBatch.End();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please change your `bricks` class name to `Bricks`. Code by the standards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You never Initialise the bricks object.
You need to call `bricks.Initialise();` function somewhere (preferably in the initialise function of the `Breakout` class).

I would also recommend you to use a bit cleaner code standard.
Class names usually start with upper case, ie: `Bricks` instead of `bricks`, in your case, the class and the instance of the class have the same name (`bricks`) which could create confusion and even should create a compiler error (I think?).
(The 'NewTexture' variable in the constructor of the `brick` class also suffer from bad naming, should probably rather be named `newTexture`, especially due to the fact that the Rect is called `newRectangle`, - but this is not a code-review site, so ill leave that issue for now!).

Comment: added bricks.Initialise(); into the breakout.cs file in the inialise method and also changed the class names to uppercase. however no bricks are showing still

Comment: Check fooser's answer, it contains some information that I didn't notice: The Rectangle you pass is probably initialised with `(0,0,0,0)` (cause you use the default constructor, no args), thats not good. And you probably just want to pass null there.

Comment: yes! im with you now, I remember leaving them at 0 because i wasn't sure of the sizes. thanks for your help both of you

Comment: what parameters shall i pass the rectangle? my blocks are 30x150 so i tried: Bricks = new Bricks(Content.Load<Texture2D>("redbrick"),new Rectangle(30,30,150,150)); and the blocks have come out all weird, but when i pass null and leave them at defaults the blocks are perfect

Comment: If i remember right, the sourceRect should be (pox,posy,width,height) where all are relative to the source sprite, so: `new Rectangle(0,0,30,150);`.

Answer (score 0):

Try passing `null` into the `sourceRectangle` parameter of `spriteBatch.Draw` in your bricks class.  I think the rectangle you're passing in is no good.

```
spritebatch.Draw(brickimg, new Vector2(brickXPos[i], brickYPos[i]), null, Color.White);
```

Comment: great they are now drawing perfectly! so how would I go about drawing a rectangle around each for collision detection?

Comment: I may have to get back to you with some actual code but a good starting point for a bounding box may be:  rectangle with an origin (brickXPos[i], brickYPos[i]) and with a height of brickImg.Height and width of brickImg.Width.  Depending on how complex you get and precise you need to be, these things can get tricky if you add Scale and/or rotation to the bricks.

Comment: Why was "accepted answer" removed from this answer?  :(